# Is it possible to get parameters of an unpublished plugin without querying the database directly?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Is there a Joomla 2.5.x API that would allow for retrieval of a plugin information(i.e. parameters) if the desired plugin is unpublished?

Why: We have a few plugins that are only enabled in production and I'm looking for a way to get at some of the parameters programmatically and without querying the database directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
$userPlugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('user', 'joomla'); // group, specific - optional
  $userPluginParams = new JRegistry();
  $userPluginParams->loadString($userPlugin->params); //get the string as a jregistry
  $useStrongEncryption = $userPluginParams->get('strong_passwords', 0); // get the one you want.
```

Here's a workaround to make it not run but still able to get:

Okay how about this for a trick/workaround. Did you realize plugins have access levels? Why don't you create an access level with no one in it and assign to the plugin as the only level it runs for. Then you can publish it but it won't run.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Elin! The problem is that JPluginHelper::getPlugin() does not return anything if the desired plugin is unpublished.

Comment: Okay how about this for a trick/workaround.  Did you realize plugins have access levels? Why don't you create an access level with no one in it and assign to the plugin as the only level it runs for. Then you can publish it but it won't run.

Comment: please make that into a reply so that I can accept it. Works like a charm!

Comment: Added to the original answer.